# Object in intel xdk cannot been preview in Smartphone (apps preview)

Tags: javascript, android, html, intel-xdk

I am creating an HTML5 App using Intel XDK. The object can be preview in Intel XDK,but the problem is it cannot be preview in Apps Preview on smartphone. Only blank screen were displayed on the apps preview. How to make sure it can be preview on apps preview?

Comment: Which version of XDK are you using, there is an update with fix on v769, Can you post your code that reproduces this issue?

Comment: I'm using xdk_web_win_master_0505. This is the link of the code https://db.tt/L9o7Ckfb

Comment: get updated version 769, this fixes the issue, I tested your code on iPhone5 and Nexus5-Android4.4

Comment: I already update it to the version 769, but still cannot preview in the smartphone. I'm using Android 4.0. Do I have to use Android version 4.4?

Comment: it should work on 4.0, i will try to find a device

Comment: I already use android version 4.1 but still cannot preview the object

Answer (score 0):

There was a known issue win version 505 of Intel XDK, get the [updated version](http://xdk-software.intel.com/) 769, this version fixes the blank screen issue.

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready",init,false); 
</script>
```

to `index.html` and it worked on an Android 4.0.4 device

Comment: I still cannot preview it on Android device. Is it because of the coding or the device?

Comment: what device did you use? i still cannot preview it using my device. I'm using Sony xperia and ninetology